# How do I print the total of random numbers without making the random numbers variables in Python?

Tags: python, random

So I'm making a random number generator and I want to be able to print the total. I've done this before but had all the random numbers, like this: `die1 = random.randrange(1, 10)`
Here's my code:

```
import random
while True:
    dicenumber = raw_input('How many die are you rolling?>')
    dicesize = raw_input('What size die are you rolling?>')
    rolls = int(dicenumber)
    while rolls > 0:
        print random.randrange(1, int(dicesize))
        #print the total of the numbers? 
        rolls = rolls - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could this with a generator expression and the `sum` builtin:

```
dicesize = int(dicesize)
dicenumber = int(dicenumber)
print sum(random.randrange(1, dicesize) for _ in range(dicenumber))
```

Basically, the generator expression loops `dicenumber` times, each time it yields a new random integer to `sum`.  Sum picks up the random integers and adds them all together until the generator stops generating.  At that point, the total is returned from `sum` and printed.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "diceroller.py", line 32, in <module>
    print sum(random.randrange(1, int(dicesize)) for _ in range(dicenumber))
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Python

Comment: @Joshkinz  Try: `print sum(random.randrange(1, int(dicesize)) for _ in range(int(dicenumber)))`

Comment: It should be `randrange(1, int(dicesize) + 1)` because the endpoint is not included in the selection.

Comment: @tdelaney -- Likely yes, but I was just copying OP's code :-)

Comment: Or `randint(1, dicesize)`. Rolling dice is one of the few places where `randint` is more readable…

Answer (score -1):

Based on what I understood, here is the answer:

```
import random
dicenumber=5    # set to some value >0
while dicenumber > 0:    # while True is a bad idea
    dicenumber = raw_input('How many die are you rolling?>')
    dicenumber = int(dicenumber)
    if dicenumber > 0:
       dicesize = raw_input('What size die are you rolling?>')
       rolls = int(dicenumber)
       sum=0
       while rolls > 0:
          sum=sum + random.randrange(1, int(dicesize)) 
          #print the total of the numbers? 
          rolls = rolls - 1
       print "the sum is=" , sum
    else:
      break
```

Make sure you indent your code correctly. Furthermore did you realize you have a while loop that runs forever in your prototype? You will have to clean up my code too. I have computed int(dicenumber) more than once which is not necessary.

Comment: This is a really clumsy and verbose way to do it. Why use a `while` loop with an explicit index instead of a `for` loop? Also, you don't need both a `while` condition and a `break` that tests the same condition.

Comment: Why the down vote if it works? You are free to make your comments. You are driving me away from this site. I had only one point and you took that away too? Was I not trying to be helpful here? Besides When I tried the top voted answer I also got the same error "Traceback (most recent call last): File "diceroller.py", line 32, in <module> print sum(random.randrange(1, int(dicesize)) for _ in range(dicenumber)) TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str. –"

Comment: my answer works but has been down voted and the other answer which does not work has +2. strange!!

Comment: The other answer does work. [See it working here.](http://repl.it/1ra) Meanwhile, the purpose of votes is to make the best answer float to the top, not to make you feel better, or even to encourage you to contribute. That's especially true if you're not contributing good answers, but even if you were, it's not relevant. If you're going to take votes so personally, you're not going to be happy here.

Comment: It did not work at the time it was voted. It was edited. Read the  comments by the OP below that answer.

Comment: Well, I know at least one of the upvotes to that question came after the last edit, because I voted on it after adding my comment, which I made sure to test (because I get `randint` and `randrange` backward often enough that I always check that I'm write before writing a comment that makes me look like an idiot…). At any rate, who cares whether the answer originally had a trivial mistake that it no longer does? As it stands now, it's a great answer with simple, working code, and a good explanation of what it's doing, so it deserves upvotes, and it has some. What are you complaining about?